# Functions of the vi editor working differently after updates

Tags: updates, laptop, vi

It appears that after some of the updates for my ubuntu **16.04**,
certain keys in the **vi** editor started to work differently.

In particular, the function of returning to the previous 
position, previously available as a double-click on ´,
is not working anymore. In fact `´` itself is generated
only after two consecutive clicks on it.

Is there
any way to have this function (of returning to
the previous vi position) back again?

Likewise, it seems that using a buffer,
which is necessary when one transfers
several pieces of text from one file to
another, is no longer working. Apparently,
this is also related to the `´` key, which
is used (with Shift) to specify the buffer
function.

Interestingly, I had this latter
problem in the original system, but then it
disappeared after some updates and vi was 
working nicely. Now, however, it seems to
be back again. Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's vi and not vim ? In vim, it's either single quote `'` or reverse quote ` but not forward quote as you said. May be it's a mistake ? To clarify, when you talk about buffer, it is in fact about register, right ? available with `"` ?

Comment: Its is probably vim. Although I am using vi command, the system seems to be invoking vim. This is probably called register,  the one used with a letter name when transferring from one file to another. My laptop keyboard actually has just ´ or ¨ (produced     with Shift). The latter is used for naming a register, whereas the former for getting back to the previous location within the file. But after some updates, both are now requiring double hitting the key, which was not the case previously. I suspect this double hitting is the source of the problem, why both functions ceased working. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried an alternate keyboard layout, if there is one available for oyu ?

Comment: How can I change the layout? This is just the laptop keyboard.

Comment: The ` key is actually also available along with ~. Like ~, it also now requires double hitting. When I press four times (instead of two) on `, it does seem to allow me to return to the previous position in vi, although this is highly inconvenient. The register, however,   does not seem to be working even with accurate double hitting on ¨. Note also that ´ was previously used to return to a previous position within vi instead of the one with opposite slope under ~.

Comment: The solution is actually available, though somewhat inconvenient. ´+Alt produce '.  ¨+Alt (i.e. ´+Shift+Alt) produce ". In this case, ' seems to work as necessary to return to the previous location in vim, while " seems to allow to use registers. It is just inconvenient that another key (Alt) also has to be involved. It is also clear that updates do change key definitions at least for the laptop.

Comment: Also ~ and ` are produced with Alt+Shift  and with Alt, respectively, without double hitting.